# Converter String em Float

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou tentando converter string em float para calcular á vantagem entre gasolina e etanol, porém não está retornando resultado em Tela.

Abaixo o código HTML e JS:

```js
var etanol, gasolina;

function Vantagem(){
 etanol = parseFloat(txtEtanol.value.replace(",","."));
 gasolina = parseFloat(txtGasolina.value.replace(",","."));

 if (etanol < 0.7 * gasolina) {
  document.getElementById('status').src="img/medidorEtanol.jpg";

 } else{
  document.getElementById('status').src="img/medidorGasolina.jpg";
 }
}

function Limpar(){
 document.getElementById('status').src="img/medidorNeutro.jpg";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

 <head>
  <meta charset = 'UTF-8'>

  <title> Calculadora de Combustível </title>


 </head>

 <body>

  <header>

   <h1> Calculadora de Combustível </h1>
 

  </header>

  <img src='img/medidorNeutro.jpg' id="status">


  <form name="frmFlex">

   Etanol: <input type="text" name="txtEtanol" placeholder="Etanol"> <br/>
   Gasolina: <input type="text" name="txtGasolina" placeholder="Gasolina"> <br/>

   <button onclick="Vantagem()"> Vantagem </button> <br/>
   <button onclick="Limpar()"> Limpar </button> <br/>

  </form>
    
    
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use o método `etanol = +txtEtanol.value.replace(",",".");
 gasolina = +txtGasolina.value.replace(",",".");

` em vez do parseFloat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu código tem alguns problemas:

- na linha `etanol = parseFloat(txtEtanol.value.replace(",","."));`, onde foi definida a variável `txtEtanol`?
- no seu input, não seria melhor definir "txtEtanol" como `id` no lugar de `name`?
- por que declarar as variáveis globais `var etanol, gasolina;` se só está usando na *function*?
- para comparar e garantir a operação com a gasolina, adicione um parênteses aqui: `if (etanol < 0.7 * gasolina)`

Para simplificar um poco o código, criei esse exemplo:

```js
function Vantagem() {
    var etanol = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtEtanol').value.replace(",", "."));
    var gasolina = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtGasolina').value.replace(",", "."));

    if (etanol < (0.7 * gasolina)) {
        document.getElementById('status').src = "img/medidorEtanol.jpg";
        alert('medidorEtanol'); // apenas para testar

    } else {
        document.getElementById('status').src = "img/medidorGasolina.jpg";
        alert('medidorGasolina'); // apenas para testar
    }
}

function Limpar() {
    document.getElementById('status').src = "img/medidorNeutro.jpg";
}
```

```html
<header>
   <h1> Calculadora de Combustível </h1>
</header>
<img src='img/medidorNeutro.jpg' id="status">

   Etanol: <input type="text" id="txtEtanol" placeholder="Etanol"> <br/>
   Gasolina: <input type="text" id="txtGasolina" placeholder="Gasolina"> <br/>
   <button onclick="Vantagem()"> Vantagem </button> <br/>
   <button onclick="Limpar()"> Limpar </button> <br/>
```

Comment: Se ele trocasse ParseFloat para `+` seria mesma coisa?

Comment: como o que colocou no comentário? `etanol = +txtEtanol.value.replace(",",".")`? desconheço essa sintaxe por isso não sei se funciona, mas não me parece claro, mas de qualquer forma vai dar erro por `txtEtanol` não está definido

Comment: Dar certo. Essa sintaxe transforma em número.

Comment: @MauryDeveloper Com o `+` seria a mesma coisa pois `+` seguido de uma `string` o `Javascript` tenta converter para numero como se tivesse feito `+ Number(texto)` que tanto funcionará quer o texto tenha um numero inteiro ou um `float`

Comment: Sim isso mesmo. Eu queria ajuda,mas ele não consegui entende.

Comment: interessante, nunca fiz dessa maneira, mas de qq forma acho o `parseFloat` mais claro, assim como `Number` :)